# Retry HttpClient request without handlers

Tags: c#, http, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api

I have a server and client application. In the client application, there are HttpRequestException class exceptions on requests. As it seems to me - these exceptions happen in isolated cases and not always speak about a connection problem. So I decided to do a repeat of the queries with a small amount of time:

```
private static async Task<T> RetryRequest<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, int retryCount = 3, int retryTimeout = 1000)
{
    var tryCount = 0;
    Exception lastException = null;
    while (tryCount < retryCount)
    {
        tryCount++;
        try
        {
            return await func.Invoke();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            lastException = exception;
            await Task.Delay(retryTimeout);
        }
    }

    if (lastException != null)
        throw lastException;

    throw new HttpRequestException("Can't get request after retrying");
}
```

Usage example:

```
public async Task<List<NewsItemDto>> GetNewsAsync(DateTime date)
{
    return await RetryRequest(async () =>
    {
        var sd = date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", null);
        var query = new { date = sd };
        var queryString = query.ToQueryString();
        var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/{ModPlusPlatformRoute}/news{queryString}").ConfigureAwait(false);

        await response.HandleErrorAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await response.GetDataAsync<List<NewsItemDto>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    });
}
```

HandleErrors:

```
public static async Task HandleErrorAsync(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    if ((int)response.StatusCode >= 400)
    {
        MediaTypeHeaderValue ct = response.Content.Headers.ContentType;
        if (ct != null && ct.MediaType == "text/html")
            throw new ClientException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), response.StatusCode.ToString());

        ErrorModel errorModel = await response.GetDataAsync<ErrorModel>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (errorModel != null)
            throw new ClientException(errorModel.Error, errorModel.StatusCode.ToString());

        var webException = new WebException($"Error with code: {response.StatusCode}");
        AppMetrica.SendHttpException(webException, response.RequestMessage.ToString());
        throw webException;
    }
}
```

Work method I checked as best I could - everything seems fine. But I am confused by too much use of asynchrony

Comment: Any reason for not using an existing solution like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)?

Comment: Feel you are reinventing the wheel.  You can do this with the httpclient see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650002 for example of having the client retry.  If you don't have to have the httpclient then I would also recommend looking into Polly

Comment: @BohdanStupak Yes, there is a reason why I cannot use third-party libraries in my project

Comment: @CharlesNRice 
I saw that topic. Judging by the discussions in that version, there are a lot of problems. Some of them have already been discussed there and there is probably a part that is not yet known. My option seemed simpler to me and required less alterations in the code